# Libreria Math (Python)

Tags: python, math

Tengo un problema o duda con la librería `math`.
Yo se, que el `sin(90) = 1`; formulando esa operación en cualquier otra calculadora científica, me da el resultado correcto; pero al momento de utilizar la librería `math` no me es posible hallar el mismo valor.

Dejo aquí un ejemplo del `sin(90)`:

```py
import math

math.sin(90)  # Resultado: 0.8939966636005579
```

Otra versión para verificar, según cualquier calculadora, el `sin(8) = 0.139173101`, al utilizar la libreria `math`, el resultado esperado es otro.

Dejo aquí un ejemplo del `sin(8)`:

```py
import math

math.sin(8)  # Resultado: 0.9893582466233818
```

¿A qué se puede deber esos resultados?

Saludos!

Comment: el parametro que espera python es en grados(radianes) para ello debes hacer algo como `math.sin(math.radians(90))`

Comment: Los ángulos pueden medirse en grados, que es a lo que estamos acostumbrados y lo que suelen usar las calculadoras, o en radianes, que es la unidad preferida por los matemáticos y en este caso por Python. La conversión la puedes hacer sabiendo que 180 grados equivale a "pi" radianes. O dejar que la haga python con la operación `math.radians()`, como te ha indicado @JackNavaRow

Comment: Para complementar lo comentado, dejo un enlace a la documentación: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/math.html#math.sin. La definición de la función dice _`math.sin(x)`:  Return the sine of **x radians**_.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos, todo mas que claro y probado!

Answer (score 1):

EL problema es que math.sin y todas las funciones trigonometricas de esta libreria trabajan en radianes. Por ejemplo, 90 grados es equivalente a pi/2 radianes. Entonces prueba

```
import math

print(math.sin(math.pi / 2))
```